# Want to know the process to pursue diploma in piano

Tags: piano, exam-grades

I am a grade 6 student in piano from LCM. I want to pursue a career in music. All I know so far is, after grade 8 I need to have a diploma. Can anyone elaborate on  the career path? Is there a prerequisite for the diploma? What is the road after the diploma? And what is the duration for completing the diploma?

Comment: This information can better be sourced from trinity guildhall or abrsms website.

Comment: There is no "road after the diploma", or rather, there are any number of roads. And for specifics on a diploma, you should look at the website for the institution that supplies it.